# Creating new pages via code (Asp.Net Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

How can I add and create new razor pages and folders via code using Asp.NET Core?

Comment: I am not sure why you want to, but perhaps what you are trying to accomplish can be done more easily than this. What is the end goal for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

According to your needs, I think you want a hint similar to the code generator.

You can [use T4 Text Templates for code generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019).

**I suggest you read the code of [Generator-ASP.NET-Core-MVC](https://github.com/neron1234/Generator-ASP.NET-Core-MVC), it should help you.**

#### Example link and picture

[ManageChangePassword.tt](https://github.com/neron1234/Generator-ASP.NET-Core-MVC/blob/master/src/Common/Templates/Views/Manage/ManageChangePassword.tt)

[image]